# Mongo C# Driver - How to apply ToLower() to a DistinctAsyc

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am retrieving a list of strings from MongoDB using `DistinctAsync`. The problem is that the results are distinct except that I get some values all in uppercase and some are in lower case which count as distinct of course.

How could I apply a `.ToLower()` to this query?

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetAllAuthorsUserNames()
{
    var filter = Builders<Episode>.Filter.Where(x => x.CreatedBy != null);

    var cursor = await GetCollection().DistinctAsync(o => o.CreatedBy, filter);

    return cursor.ToList();
}
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var cursor = await GetCollection().DistinctAsync(o => o.CreatedBy.ToLower(), filter);
```

Comment: It gives me this error: `Unable to determine the serialization information for o => o.CreatedBy.ToString().ToLower()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various approaches you can take to yield the result you want. Some are:

1. Store the authors's names in lowercase only (or at least in a consistent manner such that you do not have to transform their names to yield distinct ones among them in the first place) and in that case a distinct query alone is enough to get you the desired result.
2. After you fetch the distinct authors's names from the current data, map their names to their respective lowercase version in-memory and then apply another distinct function on it to get all authors's names in lowercase and distinct form. That will look like:

```
var filter = ...
var cursor = await GetCollection().DistinctAsync(v => v.CreatedBy, filter);
var list = await cursor.ToListAsync();

var names = list.Select(v => v.ToLower()).Distinct().ToList();
```

3. Use aggregation. Basically, you can `project` all authors's names to their respective lowercase form (see: [toLower](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/)) and then `group` all the projected lowercase names to a set (see: [addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/)). That set will be your result which you can extract from the aggregated result.

My opinion is that you should consider altering your data so as to not add unnecessary computational complexity which takes up valuable resources. If that is not possible, but the names themselves are relatively few, you can use the second approach. Use the third approach with the understanding that it is not the ideal and it will add to more processing on the part of your DBMS.

Comment: Hello! Thanks, I thought it would be possible to use the MongoDB C# driver only but using LINQ in step 2 solved the problem. Step 3 was not necessary. Thanks!